# Start elasticsearch within gradle build for integration tests

Tags: java, elasticsearch, gradle

Is there a way to start elasticsearch within a gradle build before running integration tests and afterwards stop elasticsearch?

My approach so far is the following, but this blocks the further execution of the gradle build.

```
task runES(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    systemProperties = ["es.path.home":"$buildDir/elastichome",
                        "es.path.data":"$buildDir/elastichome/data"]
}
```

Comment: You just need to run it in background, but this is not possible with `JavaExec.`

Comment: Yes unfortunately this is not implemented yet. There is an issue for that: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1254

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my purpose i have decided to start elasticsearch within my integration test in java code.

I've tried out [ElasticsearchIntegrationTest](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/integration-tests.html) but that didn't worked with spring, because it didn't harmony with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.

I've found it easier to start elasticsearch in the before method:

My test class testing some 'dummy' productive code (indexing a document):

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.notNullValue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings.Builder;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.indices.IndexAlreadyExistsException;
import org.elasticsearch.node.Node;
import org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyIntegrationTest {

    private Node node;
    private Client client;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        createElasticsearchClient();
        createIndex();
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        this.client.close();
        this.node.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
        // do something with elasticsearch
        final String json = "{\"mytype\":\"bla\"}";
        final String type = "mytype";
        final String id = index(json, type);
        assertThat(id, notNullValue());
    }

    /**
     * some productive code
     */
    private String index(final String json, final String type) {
        // create Client
        final Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "mycluster").build();
        final TransportClient tc = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(
                "localhost", 9300));

        // index a document
        final IndexResponse response = tc.prepareIndex("myindex", type).setSource(json).execute().actionGet();
        return response.getId();
    }

    private void createElasticsearchClient() {
        final NodeBuilder nodeBuilder = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder();
        final Builder settingsBuilder = nodeBuilder.settings();
        settingsBuilder.put("network.publish_host", "localhost");
        settingsBuilder.put("network.bind_host", "localhost");
        final Settings settings = settingsBuilder.build();
        this.node = nodeBuilder.clusterName("mycluster").local(false).data(true).settings(settings).node();
        this.client = this.node.client();
    }

    private void createIndex() {
        try {
            this.client.admin().indices().prepareCreate("myindex").execute().actionGet();
        } catch (final IndexAlreadyExistsException e) {
            // index already exists => we ignore this exception
        }
    }
}
```

It is also very important to use elasticsearch version 1.3.3 or higher. See [Issue 5401](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/5401).