# Elasticsearch 6.2 (java/gradle) integration test

Tags: elasticsearch, integration-testing, gradlew

I am spending days trying to find solution what to use for  this "simple" test:

- inside of test stand up ES node that will be used for test only
- connect with transport client to that ES instance and add new index.
  (that is just a start of all integration tests, but I need to see how
  to do one if anyone has an example)

Note: we have to continue to use transport client, we know it is going away.

We are upgrading from ES version 2 to version 6 and trying to keep integration tests as much unchanged as possible.
This is exactly the same issue as this person had in lower version, we had it that way but it is not supported anymore in 6, and how do I accomplish the same now: [Start elasticsearch within gradle build for integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489172/start-elasticsearch-within-gradle-build-for-integration-tests)

I am finding comments about "existing gradle plugin" will do the job - what is that plugin and how to use it?

Or, example with ESIntegTestCase would be perfect too, anything that works. Thank you!

Comment: what is the question here? what did you try to do? post the steps you are trying to take in a clear manner, what you expect, and how it doesn't work that way.

Comment: 1. inside of test stand up ES node that will be used for test only
2. connect with transport client to that ES instance and add new index. 

(that is just a start of all integration tests, but I need to see how to do one if anyone has an example)

Comment: you asked why I need this: we had test that is starting embedded node in old ES version, and testing all of our service features against that node. Upgrading to version 6 and starting embedded node is not supported anymore. I still need to run those tests on test elasticsearch instance that I should spin from test and get rid of it after.

Comment: This is exactly the same issue as this person had in lower versions, but problem is this is not supported anymore in 6: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489172/start-elasticsearch-within-gradle-build-for-integration-tests

Comment: cool update the question so that it's clear and let's try to get people to see it.